# Editing question changing code to block quote is still formatted as code

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting, blockquote

I asked [a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660070/how-to-parse-rtsp-request-and-response-headers) and later added some more information. I included a quote initially in a code block, but then I edited the question, highlighted those two lines, and clicked the "block quote" button on the top, thus adding `>` to the beginning of each line. While in edit mode, the preview showed it formatted as a quote. But after saving, the page is showing it still formatted as code. You can tell because the two words `to` and `or` are navy blue.

To test, I copied the URL from one browser to another browser. I can still see the two blue words, indicating it's formatted as code instead of a quote.

Comment: No repo. Looks fine for me.

Comment: When looking at the code insight, the `to` and `or` are in their own span, which formats the font color as navy blue.

Comment: oh ok... makes sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you have it formatted is a code block *inside* a blockquote. You still have 4 spaces in front of the text in the blockquote, so the Markdown parser still thinks it's code. Just clicking the blockquote button does not automatically undo code-formatted text inside it.

Removing the spaces fixes the problem.

Comment: Ahh, that explains it. One of those "duh" things :D